# Illegal sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTimeOffset

Tags: odata, sap-fiori, datetimeoffset, sapb1

Posting for prosperity.  I had zero hits from google.

I'm writing a SAP Business One Web Client extension.  I'm using the worklist template and have the b1s/v2/ Service Layer metadata (auto generated while setting up the template)

Running the sandbox version ("npm run start-local") it automatically generates fake data based on the metadata. My data included an `edm.DateTimeOffset` which is resolved by Fiori using the sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTimeOffset model.

Here is an example response object from the test data proxy (all autogenerated)

```
{
  DocEntry: 1,
  U_CardCode: "U_CardCode_0",
  U_CardName: "U_CardName_0",
  U_DocCurrency: "U_DocCurrency_0",
  U_DocTotal: "",
  U_DueDate: "2017-04-13T14:50:39.000Z",
  U_Status: "U_Status_0",
  U_SupplierInvNo: "U_SupplierInvNo_0",
}
```

A perfectly normal `U_DueDate` value that, according to all the documentation I could find is an accepted format, doublely confirmed by the fact that it's a sap generated value.

This produces an error on screen

> Illegal sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTimeOffset

Adding a formatter doesn't work.  If it's unable to parse the value then it won't pass it on to a formatter.

Comment: Is the `U_DueDate` entity property referring to a specific date value only without any time information? Or is it really a timestamp that is supposed to contain the time information? And what is the target SAPUI5 version? Or with which SAPUI5 version is the app currently running? The format `"2017-04-13T14:50:39.000Z"` for an `Edm.DateTimeOffset` value is valid only in OData **V4**. Is the service really based on OData V2?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a way to override the expected type in the metadata.  I couldn't find much documentation on it, but I changed the element from

```
text="{'U_DueDate'}" />
```

to

```
text="{
  path: 'U_DueDate',
  targetType: 'any',
  formatter: '.formatter.date'
}" />
```

The date is now accepted as a string so I can use a custom formatter.
Here is the date function in the formetter:

```
    date : function (sValue) {
        if (!sValue) {
            return "";
        }
        var date = new Date(sValue)
        var asString = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB")
        return asString;
    }
```

You don't have to hard code the localization, but my use case is that niche